# Can we check if the request is processed within particular time using gatling

Tags: gatling

For example: Can we check if the page is loaded within 3 seconds or any desired time.

I want to test a webpage, that it is opened within 3 seconds or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered your question on Gatling's Group : https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/gatling/ftU2iegpSuo